# How To Test OOP Php Functions In POSTMAN Rest API

Tags: php, oop, methods, mysqli, postman

I'm practicing making `php` script in an `OOP` format. And I'm about to test my `methods` in my `php` script. The problem is, **how do I specifically test those `methods` that I made?**

[image: POSTMAN]

`http://localhost/tryhard/OOP/dbConnectClass.php` -  Where should I place them the `method` name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Postman** is build for building, testing and documenting APIs. If you want to test your method You must have to create a **PHP** file, import the class file, create object and call the method.

You can't directly call methods in Postman.

Create file like this:

**Filename: testapi.php**

```
<?php

import('dbConnectClass.php');

$dbConnect=new DBConnect(); // Assuming class name is DBConnect()
$returnvalue=$dbConnect->methodName();
echo $returnvalue;

// You can return output as JSON here.    

?>
```

Comment: Ahh, yes. I forgot. I need to create an php file to like `index.php` and do those things that you posted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
<?php
class parent{
    function __construct() {
        $self::mymethod();
    }

    public function mymethod(){
        //do your thing
    }
}

$class_object = new parent();
?>
```

when you will call `dbConnectClass.php` php script will execute, it will create class object and constructor will call automatically and your method will called.

something like this i am using in my current project.